# Beamer: Custom theme breaks when using dual screen presentation mode

Tags: beamer, margins, themes, pgfpages

The following small beamer example

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\usetheme[department=compute]{DTU}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{content}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

tries to use the dual-screen note feature of Beamer (first three commands), but my university theme is causing problems. As you can tell from the image below, it is cutting off part of the footer (and likely the header as well).

[image: produced pdf]

This does not happen without:

```
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
```

The [full theme](http://latex.dtu.dk/?page_id=61) is available online; a bit too long to paste in unfortunately. Anything I could try to stretch the margins would be helpful as well.

p.s. tried making changes to the theme files to see if anything helped, but the main file did not respond to any changes, not even if I introduced syntax errors. I am using Texstudio and TexLive on Ubuntu and called `texhash` and cleaned auxiliary files; is Texstudio using a cached version of the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme modifies the paper size, therefore it needs to be loaded before before `pgfpages`.

Please also note that the `notes` document class option is obsolete. Use beamer option `show notes` instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[department=compute]{DTU}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

%\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{content}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thought it might the paper size adjustment, but nice to know that you can get it working without messing with the actual theme.